# Drawing on the UITableViewCell by overriding the drawRect method

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, drawrect, uibezierpath

I wrote following code to provide rounded corner to top tableViewCell. It is working fine with iOS 6. But for iOS 7, it is not drawing the corner.

```
       UIBezierPath* roundedRectanglePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height) byRoundingCorners: UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight cornerRadii: size];
    [[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];
    [roundedRectanglePath fill];
    [[UIColor lightGrayColor] setStroke];
    roundedRectanglePath.lineWidth = 1;
    [roundedRectanglePath stroke];
```

Comment: can you put the output image in ios6?

Comment: Have you thought about using a shape layer?

Comment: I think you should over ride the draw rect method of you table view instead of UITableViewCell..

Comment: @Wain: I am not yet used shape layer. Let me try once.

Comment: I created separate UIView and added above code to the drawRect method for that view. And that view is added as contentView for that cell. This solved my problem. 
     Is it the think, Apple changed the view hierarchy?